# open file if it exists, otherwise, create a new one and open it

Tags: bash, emacs, alias

I currently have the following alias set up:

```
alias emacs='open -a Emacs'
```

But obviously, if the file doesn't exist already, it gives me an error. Is there a way to change this alias to basically say "if the file exists open it in Emacs, otherwise, create the file and then open it in Emacs?"

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you file a bug report to the authors of `open` about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a function instead of an alias. Functions can do everything aliases can do and much more.

```
emacs() {
    if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
        touch "$1"
    fi
    open -a Emacs "$1"
}
```

That should work for one file. For multiple files you can use this.

```
emacs() {
    for file; do
        if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
            touch "$file"
        fi
    done
    open -a Emacs "$@"
}
```

Comment: I was getting an error in the function declaration. It worked when I changed it to `function emacs` with no parentheses

Comment: What shell are you using? `(t)csh`?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider an alias with `--args` option for `open` command like this:

```
alias emacs='open -a Emacs --args= '
```

Then call it as:

```
emacs $PWD/file.txt
```

As per `man open`:

```
--args
     All remaining arguments are passed to the opened application in the argv parameter
     to main(). These arguments are not opened or interpreted by the open tool.
```

Answer (score 0):

Or create a small script called omacs with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in $*; do if [ -f $f ]; then open -a Emacs $f; else touch $f; open -a Emacs $f; fi; done
```

And create this alias

```
alias emacs='omacs'
```

Works with multiple files.